# Can someone tell me how to create object of interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have to make a presentation about interfaces in Kotlin. one of my subject is "Creating interface of object" How do you do that?

Answer (score 4):

use the `object` expression

```
val instanceOfYourInterface = object : YourInterfaceHere {

    override fun methodOfYourInterfaceHere() { /*...*/ }

}
```

Read more in [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)

Comment: Why do I need to implement every Abstract open function in object from Interface if it's for slightly modification?

Comment: and why it doensn't override?

Comment: You can't leave a function abstract in a non-abstract class. Objects are always non-abstract. When you implement an interface in a non-abstract class, you are declaring that your class can invoke any of the functions of that interface.

Comment: You can make functions of your interface non-abstract by giving them an empty body `{}` (assuming they don't return anything but Unit). Any functions like this you will not have to override in your `object`.